# complex integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi }(u^{2}(re^{i\theta })-v^{2}(re^{i\theta }))d\theta $

Tags: complex-analysis

Let complex function $f(z)=u(z)+iv(z)$ be analytic on $\left | z \right |<1$ and $f(0)=2+i$. If $r$ is the real number satisfying $0<r<1$, what is the value of the integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi }(u^{2}(re^{i\theta })-v^{2}(re^{i\theta }))d\theta $?

$\int_{0}^{2\pi }(u^{2}(re^{i\theta })-v^{2}(re^{i\theta }))d\theta =\int _{\left | z \right |=r}\frac{u^{2}(re^{i\theta })-v^{2}(re^{i\theta })}{2}dz=2\pi iRes(\frac{u^{2}(re^{i\theta })-v^{2}(re^{i\theta })}{2}, 0)=2\pi i\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}z\frac{u^{2}(re^{i\theta })-v^{2}(re^{i\theta })}{2}=2\pi i\frac{u^{2}(0)-v^{2}(0)}{ri}=2\pi i\frac{3}{ri}=\frac{6\pi }{r}$

is it right...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(z)$ is analytic, then $f^2(z)=u^2(z)-v^2(z)+i2u(z)v(z)$ is also analytic.

Now, we have

$$\oint_{|z|=r}\frac{f^2(z)}z\,dz=\int_0^{2\pi}\left(u^2(re^{i\theta})-v^2(re^{i\theta})+i2u(re^{i\theta})v(re^{i\theta})\right)\,i\,d\theta\tag1$$

The Residue Theorem guarantees that

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{|z|=r}\frac{f^2(z)}z\,dz&=2\pi i f^2(0)\\\\
&=2\pi i (2+i)^2\\\\
&=-8\pi+i6\pi \tag2
\end{align}$$

If $u(z)$ and $v(z)$ are assumed to be real-valued functions, then setting the imaginary parts of $(1)$ and $(2)$ equal, we conclude that

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\left(u^2(re^{i\theta})-v^2(re^{i\theta})\right)\,d\theta=6\pi$$